# remove curly brackets from a list of sets in python

Tags: python, list, set, curly-braces

my code looks something like this:

```
documents=set()
finals = []
temporary_set= set()
temporary_set.add(i)
finals.append(documents.intersection(temporary_set))
```

when i want to get all values from the finals list i use:

```
for final in finals:
    print (final)
```

This returns however the items as a set item within a list. like this:

```
[{27309053}, {23625724}, {25051134}]
```

How can i make it that the curly brackets will be omitted and that my result will look like this:

```
[27309053, 23625724, 25051134]
```

???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change

```
finals.append(documents.intersection(temporary_set))
```

to

```
finals.extend(documents.intersection(temporary_set))
```

which will add each element of that intersection to the list, rather than the intersection itself.

Comment: Great! this was exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten your list of sets using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
import itertools

x = [{27309053}, {23625724}, {25051134}]

list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x))
# [27309053, 23625724, 25051134]
```

Comment: they could but it would better to go back a step on not create a list of sets in the first place

Comment: I agree. But the question was essentially that they end up with a list of sets, and want it turned into a flat list...

Comment: if you intupret the question that way, then it's a common duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python (Patrick's approach is better IMO)

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the code upstream by using [`extend`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53213635/3620003) is the way to go here.

If you end up with a list

```
l = [{27309053}, {23625724}, {25051134}]
```

where you can't modify how it's created, you can use iterable unpacking like this:

```
>>> l = [{27309053}, {23625724}, {25051134}]
>>> [x for x, in l]
>>> [27309053, 23625724, 25051134]
```

Comment: Better:  `[x for [x] in l]`  (non-destructive, and validates sets are 1 item only)

Comment: @wim Good idea, I modified my answer with the tuple version of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
l = [{27309053}, {23625724}, {25051134}]

[x for sl in l for x in sl]  # evaluates to [27309053, 23625724, 25051134]
```